# game of fifteen in C. Segmentation fault

Tags: c, cs50

My code returns a segmentation fault. I just started to code functions `init` and `draw`.

It's written in C and is from the cs50 thing.

This is my code:

```
/**
* fifteen.c
*
* Implements Game of Fifteen (generalized to d x d).
*
* Usage: fifteen d
*
* whereby the board's dimensions are to be d x d,
* where d must be in [DIM_MIN,DIM_MAX]
*
* Note that usleep is obsolete, but it offers more granularity than
*  sleep and is simpler to use than nanosleep; `man usleep` for more.
*/

#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 500

#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

// constants
#define DIM_MIN 3
#define DIM_MAX 9

// board
int board[DIM_MAX][DIM_MAX];

// dimensions
int d;

// prototypes
void clear(void);
void greet(void);
void init(void);
void draw(void);
bool move(int tile);
bool won(void);

int main(int argc, string argv[]) {
    // ensure proper usage
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: fifteen d\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // ensure valid dimensions
    d = atoi(argv[1]);
    if (d < DIM_MIN || d > DIM_MAX)
    {
        printf("Board must be between %i x %i and %i x %i, inclusive.\n",
            DIM_MIN, DIM_MIN, DIM_MAX, DIM_MAX);
        return 2;
    }

    // open log
    FILE *file = fopen("log.txt", "w");
    if (file == NULL)
    {
        return 3;
    }

    // greet user with instructions
    greet();

    // initialize the board
    init();


    // accept moves until game is won
    while (true)
    {
        // clear the screen
        clear();

        // draw the current state of the board
        draw();

        // log the current state of the board (for testing)
        for (int i = 0; i < d; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < d; j++)
            {
                fprintf(file, "%i", board[i][j]);
                if (j < d - 1)
                {
                    fprintf(file, "|");
                }
            }
            fprintf(file, "\n");
        }
        fflush(file);

        // check for win
        if (won())
        {
            printf("ftw!\n");
            break;
        }

        // prompt for move
        printf("Tile to move: ");
        int tile = get_int();

        // quit if user inputs 0 (for testing)
        if (tile == 0)
        {
            break;
        }

        // log move (for testing)
        fprintf(file, "%i\n", tile);
        fflush(file);

        // move if possible, else report illegality
        if (!move(tile))
        {
            printf("\nIllegal move.\n");
            usleep(500000);
        }

        // sleep thread for animation's sake
        usleep(500000);
    }

    // close log
    fclose(file);

    // success
    return 0;
}

/**
* Clears screen using ANSI escape sequences.
*/
void clear(void) {
    printf("\033[2J");
    printf("\033[%d;%dH", 0, 0);
}

/**
* Greets player.
*/
void greet(void) {
    clear();
    printf("WELCOME TO GAME OF FIFTEEN\n");
    usleep(2000000);
}

/**
* Initializes the game's board with tiles numbered 1 through d*d - 1
* (i.e., fills 2D array with values but does not actually print them).
*/
void init(void)
{
    int x = 0;
    int z = 0;
    int y = d * d;
    int w = 1;
    for (x = 0; x < d; x++)
    {
        for (z = 0; z < d;x++)
        {
            board[x][z] = y - w;
            w++;
        }
    }
    board[d-1][d-1] = y;

    if (y % 2 == 0)
    {
        board[d - 1][d - 2] = 2;
        board[d - 1][d - 3] = 1;
    }
}

/**
* Prints the board in its current state.
*/
void draw(void)
{
    int q = 0;
    int r = 0;

    for (q = 0; q < d; q++)
    {
        for (r = 0; r < d; r++)
        {
            printf("|%2i|", board[q][r]);
        }
    } 

    if (board[q][r] == 0)
    {
        printf(" |__|");
    }
}

/**
* If tile borders empty space, moves tile and returns true, else
* returns false.
*/
bool move(int tile) {
    // TODO
    return false;
}

/**
* Returns true if game is won (i.e., board is in winning configuration),
* else false.
*/
bool won(void) {
    // TODO
    return false;
}
```

As you can see it is still not finished.
I am a little stuck here.
Maybe somebody knows how I could get around this.
Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: SO is prompting for more info for a reason, and cheating it won't yield you any good. You haven't provided any problem description, just some incomplete long code you want us to debug.

Comment: `if (board[q][r] == 0)` in `draw` is out of bounds: `q==d` and `r==d` (for `d==DIM_MAX`).

Comment: Well I'm sorry. I mentioned that everything was good in the code until the init function so the mistake should be there. It's my first submission. I'll be better next time

Comment: Thank you so much I will have a look at that

Answer (score 3):

Change `for (z = 0; z < d; x++)` to `for (z = 0; z < d; z++)` and you won't get the segfault in `init(...)` anymore.  You just need to use a debugger to find out these types of things.  If you're using gcc try `gcc -g file.c` then run `gdb a.out` and type run

Comment: Good catch! The silly errors...

Comment: that is a great and sharp eye you've got there. Thank you !
you've guys are great helping me in such a short time!